# Setting and getting values of array from typedef struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef

**The definition of intarr_t:**

```
typedef struct {
    int* data;
    unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;
```

First, I need to set a value to a given index of array and return typedef'd status codes accordingly.

**My work for setting a value to an array is:**

```
intarr_result_t intarr_set( intarr_t* ia, 
                unsigned int index, 
                int val )
{
    if(ia == NULL)  // if ia is null
    {
        return INTARR_BADARRAY;
    }

    unsigned int len = ia->len;

    if(index >= 0 && index < len)   // if index is valid
    {
        ia[index].data = &val;  // set value at ia[index] to val

        return INTARR_OK;
    }
    else    // if index is not valid
    {
        return INTARR_BADINDEX;
    }
}
```

Second, I need to set a value of an array to a pointer variable.

**My work to get a value is:**

```
intarr_result_t intarr_get( const intarr_t* ia, 
                unsigned int index, 
                int* i )
{
    if(ia == NULL)
    {
        return INTARR_BADARRAY;
    }

    unsigned int len = ia->len;

    if((index >= 0 && index < len) && i != NULL)
    {
        i = ia[index].data;

        return INTARR_OK;
    }
    else
    {
        return INTARR_BADINDEX;
    }
}
```

When testing myself, I get a value from what I set, but the automated marker says the values returned, at the same index, from each functions is different to each other. I'm not sure where I did wrong and how I should fix it. Help me out please.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [**Array with a valid index is not returning the right status code in c**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209269/array-with-a-valid-index-is-not-returning-the-right-status-code-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
ia[index].data = &val; 
...
i = ia[index].data;
```

to

```
ia->data[index] = val; 
...
*i = ia->data[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a pointer to a local variable:

```
ia[index].data = &val;
```

int val does not exists outside the function context, hence you should not reference it.

If you want to store a pointer, change your function header:

```
intarr_result_t intarr_set( intarr_t* ia,
                            unsigned int index, 
                            int* ptr )
```

and make sure the object ptr points to still exists when calling intarr_get